# Where to put my files in netbeans project

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I am working on a web application, which uses JSF, in `netbeans`. In one of the managed bean I have to read a XML file, but I am not sure where to put this file. I have tried to put the file in `root` of project and in `src` folder too but still I am still getting a FileNotFoundException.
Please help.

Following is the stacktrace of the exception

```
Sep 29, 2012 3:59:19 PM me.uni.sushilkumar.turboblogger.PopulatePosts init
SEVERE: null
java.io.FileNotFoundException: posts.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at me.uni.sushilkumar.turboblogger.PopulatePosts.init(PopulatePosts.java:40)
at me.uni.sushilkumar.turboblogger.PopulatePosts.<init>(PopulatePosts.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:147)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getValue(UIRepeat.java:273)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getDataModel(UIRepeat.java:249)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.setIndex(UIRepeat.java:443)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:482)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.encodeChildren(UIRepeat.java:974)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1756)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:401)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:410)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Sep 29, 2012 3:59:19 PM javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot$ViewMap put
WARNING: Setting non-serializable attribute value into ViewMap: (key: posts, value     class: me.uni.sushilkumar.turboblogger.PopulatePosts)
```

Comment: Show us your code, the stack trace of the exception, and tell us what this file is. Is it some static file that is part of the webapp, enclosed in the deployable war file, or is it an external file?

Comment: wherever you add other XML files such as build files, faces-config.xml, web.xml.. :)

Comment: @chaitanya10 still getting the exception :(

Comment: @JBNizet added the stack trace. and yes it is a static file which i need to read in one of my managed bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a static file, enclosed in the deployed war file, just put it in the src directory. Netbeans will copy it tothe target location, along with the .class files. Load the file using

```
SomeClassOfTheWebApp.class.getResourceAsStream("/theXmlFile.xml");
```

and the class loader of the webapp will load it will for you.